# OpenGL doesn't seem to be reading my vertices/indices

Tags: c++, pointers, opengl

I've been following [this tutorial](http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) in a bid to learn OpenGL. I have something that works, but only if I use global variables:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>

// float vertices[] = {
//     -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
//      0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
//      0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
// };

float rectVertices[] = {
     0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  // Top Right
     0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Right
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // Bottom Left
    -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f   // Top Left 
};

uint rectIndices[] = {
    0, 1, 3,   // First Triangle
    1, 2, 3    // Second Triangle
};  

const GLchar* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;\n"

    "void main() {\n"
        "gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, position.z, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 color;\n"

    "void main() {\n"
        "color = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n";

void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) {
    if(key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
}

void finalize() {
    glfwTerminate();
}

void programExit(int code) {
    finalize();
    exit(code);
}

void enforce(int success, const char* msg, const char* info) {
    if (!success) {
        std::cerr << msg << info << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
}

// Initialise

// GLFW and OpenGL
void initialiseGLFW(int vMajor, int vMinor) {
    // Initialising GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, vMajor);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, vMinor);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
}

// Window Creation
GLFWwindow* createWindow(int width, int height, const char* title) {
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    enforce(window != nullptr, "Failed to create GLFW window", nullptr);
    return window;
}

void initialiseGLEW(bool experimental) {
    glewExperimental = experimental;
    enforce(glewInit() == GLEW_OK, "Failed to initialise GLEW", nullptr);
}

GLFWwindow* initialise(int width, int height, const char* title) {
    initialiseGLFW(3, 3);

    // Creating GLFW Window
    GLFWwindow* window = createWindow(width, height, title);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);

    // Initialising GLEW
    initialiseGLEW(true);
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    return window;
}

// Creating Shaders

void checkCompilationError(uint shader) {
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];

    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    enforce(success, "Shader compilation error: ", infoLog);
}

void checkLinkingError(uint program) {
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];

    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    glGetProgramInfoLog(program, 512, nullptr, infoLog);
    enforce(success, "Program linking error: ", infoLog);
}

uint compileShader(GLenum type, const char* source, ushort count, int* lengths) {
    uint shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(shader, count, &source, lengths);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    checkCompilationError(shader);
    return shader;
}

uint createProgram(uint vShader, uint fShader) {
    uint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fShader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    checkLinkingError(program);
    return program;
}

// Subprocedure specific to this program
uint initialiseShaders(const char* vsSource, const char* fsSource) {

    // Initialising shaders
    uint vShader = compileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource, 1, nullptr);
    uint fShader = compileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource, 1, nullptr);

    // Link program
    GLuint shaderProgram = createProgram(vShader, fShader);

    // clean up
    glDeleteShader(vShader);
    glDeleteShader(fShader);

    return shaderProgram;
}

void configureVBO(float* vertices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) std::cout << vertices[i] << std::endl;
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
    // Tell OpenGL how to interpret the vertices
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

void configureEBO(uint* indices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) std::cout << indices[i] << std::endl;
    glBufferData(
        GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
}

uint intialiseVAO(float* vertices, uint* indices) {
    uint VAO, VBO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        configureVBO(vertices);

        if (indices != nullptr) {
            glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
            configureEBO(indices);
        }
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    return VAO;
}

void execGameLoop(GLFWwindow* window, uint shaderProgram, uint VAO) {
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();

        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the program to be used
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}

int main() {

    // Config
        int width = 800, height = 800;
        const char* title = "Learn OpenGL";


    // Initialise GLFW and GLEW
    GLFWwindow* window = initialise(width, height, title);

    // Initialise Shader program
    uint shaderProgram = initialiseShaders(vertexShaderSource, fragmentShaderSource);

    // Configuring VAO, VBO and EBO
    uint VAO = intialiseVAO(rectVertices, rectIndices);

    execGameLoop(window, shaderProgram, VAO);

    finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is specifically to do with:

```
void configureVBO(float* vertices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) std::cout << vertices[i] << std::endl;
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
    // Tell OpenGL how to interpret the vertices
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}

void configureEBO(uint* indices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) std::cout << indices[i] << std::endl;
    glBufferData(
        GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
}
```

which works as expected when using the `rectVertices/Indices` global variables, but don't work when they're passed as parameters. The for-loops in each method prints the array, and they contain the values I expect them to. Why does OpenGL draw the rectangle when I use the global variables, but not when I use local parameters?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the actual code you're having a problem with.

Comment: @NicolBolas The second code snippet...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void configureVBO(float* vertices) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) std::cout << vertices[i] << std::endl;
    glBufferData(
        GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW
    );
    // Tell OpenGL how to interpret the vertices
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

The problem here is that `sizeof(vertices)` is not doing what you think it does. It doesn't tell you how many vertices are in the array -- rather, it's telling you how many bytes a variable of type `vertices` occupies. Since `vertices` is a pointer, that number is likely to be either 4 or 8 depending on your system -- but importantly, it has nothing to do with how many vertices you're actually intending to upload.

Instead, what you need to do is tell OpenGL how big you want the buffer to be, in bytes. You calculate that by `number of vertices * sizeof(vertex_type)`. So in your case that would be `12 * sizeof(float)`.

In general, you'll either need to include a second parameter to the function which includes the number of vertices, or use a `std::vector<float>` to hold your vertex data instead. For example, with a `vector` this would become:

```
void configureVBO(const std::vector<float>& vertices) {
    for (auto v : vertices) std::cout << v << "\n";
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(float),
                 vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // etc...
}
```

The reason the code worked when you used a global variable is to do with the way C++ passes arrays to functions (which in turn, it inherited from C). When you pass an array, what the function receives is just a *pointer* to the start of the array -- the information about the length of the array has been lost, so `sizeof(vertices)` can't tell you how long the array actually is. However, if you use a global variable, then the compiler can see the definition `float vertices[12]` even within the `configureVBO` function, so in that case `sizeof()` will do what you expect.

This is a very common mix-up for people getting started with C and C++. I'd really recommend using `std::vector` instead (for many reasons, of which this is just one), but it's also worth reading up on how arrays and pointers work in C and C++.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I changed `sizeof(vertices)` to `12 * sizeof(float)` and I'm still getting a blank page. The thing is that it work when the exact same data is passed as a global variable.

Comment: @Guilmon It should be `12 * sizeof(float)`, and of course you'll need to make the equivalent change in the `configureEBO()` function -- change `sizeof(indices)` to `6 * sizeof(float)`.

Comment: Ahh, changing the EBO procedure did it, thanks. But I still don't understand why I had to make that change when using the data locally as opposed to globally. I understand that I have to pass the size in bytes of the new data now, but why didn't I have to do that when using it as a global variable?

Comment: @Guilmon Updated the answer

Comment: Makes sense, that's the part I was struggling with. Thank you!